# Disabling optimize option in matlab Function

Tags: matlab, function

This is an example of Matlab itself:

```
syms x
r = x^2*(x^2 + 1);
f =  matlabFunction(r,'File','myfile','Optimize',false);
```

I wanted to disable the optimize option here.

I get this error:

```
Error using sym/matlabFunction>getOptions (line 491)
'Optimize' is not a recognized parameter. For a list of valid name-value pair arguments, see the documentation for this function.

Error in sym/matlabFunction (line 100)
opts = getOptions(args);

Error in Untitled (line 3)
f =  matlabFunction(r,'File','myfile','Optimize',false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is only available in recent versions of matlab. I recommend to use the local documentation accessible via doc to avoid such problems.

Comment: Why isn't  this mentioned in the online version of the doc? 
How can I know what has changed in each release?

Comment: You can read the release notes, there is also a documentation archive which contains the documentation for the last 10+ years

Comment: @MOON: Specifically, the `'Optimize'` is available only [for R2015a+](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/symbolic/release-notes.html#bunit3v-1). The documentation that shows up in Google searches is always for the most recent version of Matlab, so if your release is not up to date, it's a good idea to use your built-in documentation or the [archived version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html).